# How do I link to local pdf file in a create-react-app project?

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app project in which I want to link to a pdf file I have saved in my project. I suppose my questions are twofold:

1) I'm not sure where exactly I need to save the PDF file (src folder vs public folder)

2) How do I properly link to the pdf file? Right now I have something like this:

```
<a href="/portfolio-revamp/public/documents/resume.pdf">Resume</a>
```

and it's not displaying - it changes the URL but doesn't take you to the PDF.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

You need to have the file in the public folder. If you want it to open in a browser, that's what it will do. If you want to force users to download, you can add the 'download' attribute to the anchor tag.

Comment: I added the PDF to the public folder but it still doesn't link. I have the leading slash in my href because without it, each time I click the link it keeps adding to the URL. Still not sure if I need to do something else.

Comment: did you add the `download` attribute to the anchor tag as well?

Comment: I added the download tag to the anchor tag. I also had to import the pdf directly at the top of the file - that did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

1. Place the file somewhere in `src/`, for example `src/static/my-file.pdf`.
2. Import the file at the top of your component, like `import myFile from "./static/my-file.pdf";` (path is relative to `src/`).
3. Reference the object in your `a` tag: `<a href={myFile}>Link to My File</a>`

Comment: This is a better approach than using the `/public` folder, which provides no compile-time errors if the path to the file is not specified correctly

Comment: Does this even work? Maybe in normal JavaScript because TypeScript throws an error at the `import` line: `Cannot find module '../.../abc.pdf' or its corresponding type declarations.  TS2307` ?

Comment: Ugly, but u can bypass TS error using
`// @ts-ignore`

Comment: @Alex You have to add this to `/src/react-app-env.d.ts` file to make it work:

declare module '*.pdf' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in two different areas of my project, in the App component in the src folder and in a link from a child Navigation component. I created a 'docs' folder in the src directory and used require syntax to link to my file and it worked for me.

In the instance of the navigation component I accessed the file by changing the directory up two levels.

```
<Link href={require("../../docs/FILE_NAME.PDF")} target="blank">
  Resume    
<Link>
```

In the instance of the App component I searched in the same directory.

```
<Link href={require("./docs/FILE_NAME.PDF")} target="blank">
  Resume
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding "download" helped me using Create React App

```
<a
  href="/pdfname.pdf"
  download
>
  Download Resume
</a>
```

pdf location:

in public folder