# How can I open a local PDF file in another browser tab using React?

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I have a navbar link that I want to open a pdf in the browser. I am using React, created by create-react-app

My folders look like this:

```
|site
  L build
  L public
  L src
   L assets
    L file.pdf
   L components
    L navbar
```

In the navbar component, my code looks like (I followed this answer: [React - How to open PDF file as a href target blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572896/react-how-to-open-pdf-file-as-a-href-target-blank))

```
import pdf from "../assets/file.pdf"
<a href={pdf} target="_blank">File Link</a>
```

On my local host, it opens but on my deployed website, it goes to a 404. I've also tried the root path ("src/assets/file.pdf") which gets the same 404 error. I have also tried this solution ([How do I link to local pdf file in a create-react-app project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937086/how-do-i-link-to-local-pdf-file-in-a-create-react-app-project)), but my React app errors & can't path outside of the src/ folder

Comment: If you put your `assets` folder in the `public` folder and then you can simply put in the href `/assets/file.pdf`. this should work, I believe.

Comment: I get a failed to compile error in my terminal

"Module not found: You attempted to import /assets/file.pdf which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported."

Comment: Did you try like this `<a href={"/assets/file.pdf"} target="_blank">File Link</a>` after moving `assets` folder to public?

Comment: I updated the import path, but did not try adding the link directly to the href. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, by using href you'll be redirected to the pdf that is served as a static file in your web app.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the file in develop webSite You have to enter the file in the public folder

Comment: I tried to put the file directly in the public/ folder and moving the entire assets/ folder to public/ but each time it failed to compile because the href wasn't able to find the import

Comment: do you use TS file?

Comment: I do not and am not familiar with TS file. Based on my quick Google search, it's a file format to store video?

Comment: I mean typeScript file