# html download just says 'Failed - No file'

Tags: html, reactjs, download, href, anchor

I know there are a plethora of questions similar to this already, but I cannot get my link to download my pdf file. Clicking on the link says 'Resume.pdf Failed - No file'. I am using React and developing locally and Dumby.js and Resume.pdf are both directly inside the src folder:

```
import React from 'react'

const Dumby = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="./Resume.pdf" download>Resume Download</a>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Dumby
```

Comment: Putting a file inside the `src` folder doesn't get it published by the web server. How you do that depends on the bundling tool you are using.

Comment: Using create-react-app. Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you read CRA's documentation for styles and assets? You'll probably find an answer under ["adding images, fonts, and files"](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) or ["using the Public folder"](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder)

Comment: Here is your Answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937086/how-do-i-link-to-local-pdf-file-in-a-create-react-app-project

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was to import it on top.
The file is in my assets folder, and not in public :)

```
import pdf from "../assets/cv/resume.pdf";

 <a
    href={pdf}
    className='btn'
    download
    rel='noopener noreferrer'
    target='_blank'
  >
    Download cv
  </a>
```